# Should a legacy Android application be rebuilt using SDK 2.1?

Tags: android, legacy

I have an Android application that uses the well known [*Strategies for Legacy Applications*](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/practices/screens_support.html#strategies).  It is build with the Android SDK 2.0 with manifest settings minSdkVersion="3" (API 1.5) and targetSdkVersion="5" (2.0).  **Question1:** Since maxSdkVersion is not specified, the application should be installable and compatable with newly released Android versions 2.01 and 2.1 correct?  At this point in time, I am not planning any enhancements that will use any new API features.  **Question2:** is there any value in rebuilding the application with Android SDK 2.1?  **Question3:** If so, should targetSdkVersion be changed from 5 (API 2.0) to 7 (API 2.1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question1: Since maxSdkVersion is not
>   specified, the application should be
>   installable and compatable with newly
>   released Android versions 2.01 and 2.1
>   correct?

correct.

> Question2: is there any value in
>   rebuilding the application with
>   Android SDK 2.1?

not really, if you're not planning on using anything new.

> Question3: If so, should
>   targetSdkVersion be changed from 5
>   (API 2.0) to 7 (API 2.1)?

in general, targetSdkVersion should be the newest version you've tested your application on:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target